# JAVA java.io.File Read file

Tags: java, file, io, readfile

I can't understand, why in my case, `File file = new File()` can't read the existing file.

this is the code:

```
File tempDir = new File("imp_temp");
File sourceFile = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Jellyfish.jpg");

logger.info(sourceFile.length());
logger.info(sourceFile.getAbsoluteFile());
logger.info(sourceFile.canRead());
logger.info(sourceFile.isFile());
```

File 'Jellyfish.jpg' is 100% exists there, i can see it in my explorer window.
But thats what i have in log:

```
2016-07-17 17:38:13,328 INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec-5] main.IndexController (IndexController.java:201) - 0
2016-07-17 17:38:13,329 INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec-5] main.IndexController (IndexController.java:202) - C:\Users\slipo\IdeaProjects\testSpring\tomcat9\bin\imp_temp\Jellyfish.jpg
2016-07-17 17:38:13,329 INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec-5] main.IndexController (IndexController.java:203) - false
2016-07-17 17:38:13,329 INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec-5] main.IndexController (IndexController.java:204) - false
```

Why the `java.io.File` Can't see this file?

Comment: Sure it is in the `bin` folder and not `src`? Btw you may prefer to use `new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath(), "Jellyfish.jpg");` since this avoids using `File.separator` (which is already better than just `"/"` or `"\"`)

Comment: Can you post an image with the `Security` tab from the file properties menu `(right click on file -> properties -> security)`. What's the setting there for your user ?

Comment: `File file = new File()` does not read files. It doesn't do anything to the file system at all.

Comment: Consider using `File(File, String)` constructor ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String- ) to construct `sourceFile` path.

Comment: use this instead `File tempDir = new File("src"+File.separator+"imp_temp")`

Comment: @RahmatWaisi So you think his path is `[...]tomcat9\bin\src\imp_temp`? And why do you think someone has a "src" folder inside his "bin" directory?

Comment: @Tom Sorry I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Maven ? you should probably use ClassLoader, and put the file in /resources